# Citing personal correspondence with function of cited person via email?

Tags: bibtex

Which bibtex entry would should I use to cite a personal correspondence via email. Also, If I want to add the function and company (say financial controller at pencils inc.) of the person cited, how to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a list of the fields vanilla BibTeX uses on page 13 of *Tame the BeaST* ([ttb-en.pdf](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf)). I'd stick  "Personal communication" in `howpublished`; and I'm personally quite fond of the `note` field for adding sundries such as the job title of this personal communicator, and the name of his or her employer.

I do not know what citation style your style guide requires, but don't be afraid to deviate from it if it did not foresee this situation. The world will *so* not end.

[Edited January 2017 to add]

If somebody wants to add a working example to this answer, they are more than welcome. It has been years since I've used either LaTeX or BibTeX, so it would take me some time to figure out myself. In the meantime, here is an answer by Marco Daniel on another question contains code + result of [an `@misc` entry that uses the `howpublished` field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161766/2229).

Comment: Would it be possible to give an example of such a citation? Thank You

Comment: @puk, I've edited in a link. Does the linked example answer your question?