# How to quote an email address in Bibtex?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Citing personal correspondence with function of cited person via email?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59600/citing-personal-correspondence-with-function-of-cited-person-via-email)

How do you guys quote the email address of an author in your library section? What `bst` styles and `bib` packages do you use? How do you code the library entry?

That's how my German university wants to have it like (follows the rule "DIN1505").

```
Morgner, U. <morgner@uni-muenster.de> ; Steinmeyer, G. ; Mitschke,
F.: Systematic evaluation and prediction of the pulse width of
synchronously pumped lasers. URL:
<http://link.springer.de/link/service/journals/00340/bibs/8066002/80660145.htm>,
verfügbar am 1.3.1998
```

This is a weblink, I also have a book, where I want to quote the email of the author. According to [this template](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~wbl/biblio/tools/template.bib), there is an `email` field, which however is not used by Bibtex.

By the way, I use the `natbib` package and `alphadin.bst` for DIN1505 support.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion probably won't give the result you'd like, but try something like:

```
@article{MSM98,
 author = "Morgner, U. and Steinmeyer, G. and Mitschke, F.",
 title = "Systematic evaluation and prediction of the pulse width of
          synchronously pumped lasers",
 year = "1998",
 note = "{\tt morgner@uni-muenster.de}"
}
```

otherwise, try

```
@article{MSM98,
 author = "Morgner, U. {\tt morgner@uni-muenster.de} and Steinmeyer, G. and Mitschke, F.",
 title = "Systematic evaluation and prediction of the pulse width of
          synchronously pumped lasers",
 year = "1998"
}
```

Cheers