# Create interview bibliography type with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

For my thesis I need to cite interviews, which I conducted by myself, and also display them in the bibliography. 
In my .bib file I created a new entrytype called Interview.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@interview{homer,
  interviewee  = {Homer Simpson},
  interviewer = {Bart Simpson},
  date        = {2018-07-25},
  address     = {springfield},
keywords     = {interview},
}


\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
How to cite an interview. \cite{homer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bibliography entry should look like: Simpson, Homer. Interview B. Simpson, 21. August 1999, Springfield.

Moreover, it should always be cited as described above.

How can I do that with biblatex?

**EDIT:** I spent some hours with the link from moewe and the biblatex manual but I still don't get what I would like to have (or to be more precisely I just get errors).

I added the code I have so far:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@interview{homer,
    interviewee  = {Homer Simpson},
    interviewer = {Bart Simpson},
    date        = {2018-07-25},
    address     = {springfield},
    keywords     = {interview},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents}{interview.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{interview}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
  address,
}
 \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
      date}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[stackexchange]{
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
  address,
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[datamodel=interview,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{authortitle.lbx}
  \ProvidesFile{authortitle.lbx}
  \InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}
  \NewBibliographyString{interviewee, interviewer, address, date,}
  \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    interviewee   = {{interviewee}},
    interviewer     = {{interviewer}{interviewer}},
    date  = {{date}{date}},
    address    = {{address}{address}},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{authortitle}

\DeclareFieldFormat{interviewee}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat{interviewer}{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{address}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\cite{homer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435086/118739

Comment: As far as I can see it's not related to it.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864) contains a full guide on how to set up a new entry type. It is quite full on, but if you take some time to get through it, most things should work. (Of course if there is anything unclear in that answer, I'm sure the author would love to hear about it in the comments.)

The main thing that is missing is the bibliography driver (the most important bit for the output of a new entry type). The `.lbx` file was a bit off and some of the `\DeclareFieldFormats` did not make sense (either because `\DeclareFieldFormat` was used for name fields, where it does not apply or because they were redefined to just print punctuation).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@interview{homer,
  interviewee = {Homer Simpson},
  interviewer = {Bart Simpson},
  date        = {2018-07-25},
  address     = {Springfield},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents}{interview.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{interview}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[interview]{
  addendum,
  doi,
  eprint,
  eprintclass,
  eprinttype,
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
  location,
  note,
  pubstate,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[datamodel=interview,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{interview}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  interview   = {Interview},
}

\DeclareNameAlias{interviewee}{author}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{interview}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{interviewee}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \bibstring{interview}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{interviewer}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\cite{homer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Homer Simpson. Interview Bart Simpson. Springfield, 25. Juli 2018.]