# Custom type disappears in subsequent citations

Tags: biblatex

Biblatex doesn't show the same source on successive citations. I tried it with `dashed=false`, but it doesn't work. How can I make that the work is always fully cited, even on subsequent citations?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@interview{homer,
  interviewee = {Homer Simpson},
  interviewer = {Bart Simpson},
  date        = {2018-07-25},
  address     = {Springfield},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents}{interview.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{interview}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[interview]{
  addendum,
  doi,
  eprint,
  eprintclass,
  eprinttype,
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
  location,
  note,
  pubstate,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[datamodel=interview,backend=biber, dashed=false, style=authortitle, citestyle=verbose,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{interview}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  interview   = {Interview},
}

\DeclareNameAlias{interviewee}{author}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{interview}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{interviewee}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \bibstring{interview}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{interviewer}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\footcite{homer}
\footcite{homer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or is this about the citations? `dashed=false` won't help there at all. What output would you expect?

Comment: Your right, twice a citestyle doens't make sense at all. I corrected it in the code. The first footnote is  the full citation but the second is only a small green box. I would like to have the full citation twice.

Comment: `style=authortitle, citestyle=verbose,` should be the same as `style=verbose,`. Usually the subsequent citation is a shorter form with only author and title. Do you still want the full citation on subsequent cites in this case?

Comment: Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464361/35864

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that those two citestyles are the same as only verbose. Yes, I want the full citation on subsequent cites.

Comment: OK, that requires changes to the citation macros. It is a bit late for me now, but I will type up an answer tomorrow (unless there is a good answer already, of course).

Comment: I have tried to clarify the question. If you disagree with anything I have changed, please edit the question again or roll back my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles of the `verbose` family show a full citation (i.e. the full reference/bibliography entry) on a first cite and a shorter author-title citation on subsequent citations.

For the shorter author-title citation the `verbose` styles use the usual `labelname` and `labeltitle` fields. Those fields are artificial fields that take their contents from other fields in a certain order of precedence. `labelname` the first of `(short)author`, `(short)editor` and `translator`; `labeltitle` the first of `shorttitle`, `title`, `maintitle`. Our `@interview` has none of these fields and so the citation remains completely empty. One solution to get a citation would be to include fields that `@interview` has in the definitions of `labelname` and `labeltitle` so that these fields don't come out as empty.

In the comments you mentioned that `@interview`s should just be cited as full on subsequent citations as well, hence we take a slightly different route. The following MWE sets up a general structure to treat subsequent (`short` in `biblatex`-speak) citations of particular entry types differently from the rest.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@interview{homer,
  interviewee = {Homer Simpson},
  interviewer = {Bart Simpson},
  date        = {2018-07-25},
  address     = {Springfield},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents}{interview.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{interview}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[interview]{
  addendum,
  doi,
  eprint,
  eprintclass,
  eprinttype,
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
  location,
  note,
  pubstate,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[datamodel=interview,backend=biber, dashed=false, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{interview}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  interview   = {Interview},
}

\DeclareNameAlias{interviewee}{author}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{interview}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{interviewee}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \bibstring{interview}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{interviewer}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:short:interview}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}}

% cite:short is really 'cite:subsequent'
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \ifbibmacroundef{cite:short:\strfield{entrytype}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
    {\usebibmacro*{cite:short:\strfield{entrytype}}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite{homer}
ipsum\footcite{homer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the two footnotes in the MWE. Both footnotes show "Homer Simpson. Interview Bart Simpson. Springfield, 25. Juli 2018.", the second footnote is linked to the first]