# Make style=verbose's short citations for @online more verbose

Tags: biblatex

I need to change the short citation. Right now it looks as follows:
 [image]

It should look like:

> Gates, *Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation*, May 4. 2018, "Save the world..."

The "..." should appear after 3 or 4 words if that is technically possible.

How can I do that?

```
 \RequirePackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @online{gates,
        author       = {Bill Gates},
        title        = {Save the world!},
        url          = {https://www.gatesfoundation.org/de/},
        date         = {2016-07-04},
        organization = {Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation},
    }
    \end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\footcite{gates} sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \footcite{gates}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should that happen for all entry types or only for `@online`? I also feel that in this case the "..." is pretty useless, why not just include the "!" to get the full title?

Comment: This should only happen for `@online`. You're right, in this exemple it doesn't make that much sense, but with longer titles it does make sense.

Comment: Do you really want to move the access date `urldate` between `title` and `organization` here? In https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464205/35864 that place is taken by the normal publication date `date`.

Comment: No, the date should be between title and organization. I edited the question.

Comment: If by *date* you mean the date of publication as given in the `date` field, my answer should already have you covered. I assumed you did not want the `urldate`. I suggest you add the `date` to your example entry so the question makes more sense.

Comment: Note that due to the `and` in the name of the `organization` you should use double braces, either `organization = {{Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation}},` or `organization = {Bill {and} Melinda Gates Foundation},` (I mentioned that before in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464276/35864).

Comment: I just realized that your solution doesn't work with `ext-authortitle-ibid`. I'm really sorry for that.  At the point I posted the question I didn't knew that I will need to use `ext-authortitle-ibid` instead of `verbose`

Comment: In that case please ask a new question. In particular **please do not change the question significantly after you have gotten an answer** (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7678/35864). But keep in mind that `verbose` and `ext-authortitle-ibid` (or just `authortitle-ibid`) give completely different output on the first citation.

Comment: `style=ext-authortitle, citestyle=verbose-ibid` works perfectly for me. Probably there are some disadvantages to that approach but so far it works for me.

Comment: In that case a simple `style=ext-verbose-ibid` would be more natural and should give the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarly to [Custom type disappears in subsequent citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464756/35864) you need to branch the code for `cite:short` to obtain a different format for `@online` entries. A short version of the title can be specified in the `shorttitle` field. But that would require manual intervention, with Biber's sourcemapping you can automate that. I strongly suggest to scrutinise the output carefully in that case since the code is quite naive and chops off everything at the third word.

The MWE builds on the code from [Move date before title in bibliography using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464205/35864) to make the output for the full citation match the style of the short citation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{shorttitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\dots\isdot}}
\newbibmacro*{cite:short:online}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \iffieldundef{shorttitle}
      {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
      {\printfield{shorttitle}}}}

% cite:short is really 'cite:subsequent'
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \ifbibmacroundef{cite:short:\strfield{entrytype}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
    {\usebibmacro*{cite:short:\strfield{entrytype}}}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{\A(\w+\s+){2}(\w+)}, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorttitle, origfieldval, final]
      \step[fieldsource=shorttitle, match=\regexp{\A(\w+\s+)(\w+\s+)(\w+).*}, replace={$1$2$3}]
    }
  }
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlseen = {visited at}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\DeclareListWrapperFormat{organization}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{gates,
  author       = {Bill Gates},
  title        = {Save the world!},
  url          = {https://www.gatesfoundation.org/de/},
  urldate      = {2016-07-04},
  organization = {{Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation}},
}
@online{gates2,
  author       = {Bill Gates},
  title        = {Save the moon with even longer titles},
  shorttitle   = {Save the moon},
  date         = {2016-05-04},
  url          = {https://www.gatesfoundation.org/de/},
  urldate      = {2016-07-04},
  organization = {Bill {and} Melinda Gates Foundation},
}
@online{ex:one,
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  title        = {One},
  url          = {https://example.com/~elk/1},
}
@online{ex:two,
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  title        = {Two Words},
  url          = {https://example.com/~elk/2},
}
@online{ex:three,
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  title        = {Three Words Title},
  url          = {https://example.com/~elk/3},
}
@online{ex:four,
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  title        = {Four Words in Title},
  url          = {https://example.com/~elk/4},
}
@online{ex:five,
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  title        = {Five Words in a Title},
  url          = {https://example.com/~elk/5},
}
@online{ex:long,
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  title        = {This Title Is Very Long to Test the Feature},
  url          = {https://example.com/~elk/long},
}
@online{ex:override,
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  title        = {A Long Title That Will Be Overridden},
  shorttitle   = {A Different Title},
  url          = {https://example.com/~elk/over},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\autocite{gates} sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \autocite{gates2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\autocite{gates} sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \autocite{gates2}

Lorem\autocite{ex:one} ipsum\autocite{ex:one}.
Lorem\autocite{ex:two} ipsum\autocite{ex:two}.
Lorem\autocite{ex:three} ipsum\autocite{ex:three}.
Lorem\autocite{ex:four} ipsum\autocite{ex:four}.
Lorem\autocite{ex:five} ipsum\autocite{ex:five}.
Lorem\autocite{ex:override} ipsum\autocite{ex:override}.
Lorem\autocite{ex:long} ipsum\autocite{ex:long}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Fn. 1 Bill Gates. Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation. Save the world! url: https://www.gatesfoundation.org/de/ visited at 07/04/2016.//Fn. 2 Bill Gates. Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation. May 4, 2016. Save the moon with even longer titles. url: https://www.gatesfoundation.org/de/ visited at 07/04/2016.//Fn. 3 Gates, Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation, “Save the world...”//Fn. 4 Gates, Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation, May 4, 2016, “Save the moon...”//Fn. 5 Anne Elk. One. url: https://example.com/~elk/1.//Fn. 6 Elk, One.//Fn. 7 Anne Elk. Two Words. url: https://example.com/~elk/2.//Fn. 8 Elk, Two Words.//Fn. 9 Anne Elk. Three Words Title. url: https://example.com/~elk/3.//Fn. 10 Elk, “Three Words Title...”//Fn. 11 Anne Elk. Four Words in Title. url: https://example.com/~elk/4.//Fn. 12 Elk, “Four Words in...”//Fn. 13 Anne Elk. Five Words in a Title. url: https://example.com/~elk/5.//Fn. 14 Elk, “Five Words in...”//Fn. 15 Anne Elk. A Long Title That Will Be Overridden. url: https://example.com/~elk/over.//Fn. 16 Elk, “A Different Title...”//Fn. 17 Anne Elk. This Title Is Very Long to Test the Feature. url: https://example.com/~ elk/long.//Fn. 18 Elk, “This Title Is...”]

In the `match`–`replace` RegExp I went with the naive

```
match=\regexp{\A(\w+\s+)(\w+\s+)(\w+).*}, replace={$1$2$3}
```

if you want a more sophisticated solution that can be extended more easily, you could try

```
match=\regexp{\A((?:\w+\s+){2})(\w+).*}, replace={$1$2}
```

where `((?:\w+\s+){2})` captures the first 2 words and the `(\w+)` the following word.