# Custom verbose citations don't look like bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I need to modify the custom interview citation style from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464361/create-interview-bibliography-type-with-biblatex/464600#464600) post. The bibliography looks like it should. In the citation the authors name is given as "Given Family". However, the citation should look like the bibliography ("Family, Given"). How can I change that?

[image: "Homer Simpson. Interview Bart Simpson, 25. Juli 2018, Springfield."]

[image: How the citation should look like: "Simpson, Homer. Interview Bart Simpson, 25. Juli 2018, Springfield."]

```
 \RequirePackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
      @interview{homer,
        interviewee = {Homer Simpson},
        interviewer = {Bart Simpson},
        date        = {2018-07-25},
        address     = {Springfield},
      }
    \end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents}{interview.dbx}
  \DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{interview}
  \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
    interviewer,
    interviewee,
  }

  \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[interview]{
    addendum,
    doi,
    eprint,
    eprintclass,
    eprinttype,
    interviewer,
    interviewee,
    location,
    note,
    pubstate,
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[datamodel=interview,backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{interview}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  interview   = {Interview},
}

\DeclareNameAlias{interviewee}{author}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{interview}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{interviewee}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \bibstring{interview}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{interviewer}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:short:interview}{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
    \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
        \usedriver
        {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
    \ifbibmacroundef{cite:short:\strfield{entrytype}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
        \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
            \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
    {\usebibmacro*{cite:short:\strfield{entrytype}}}}

\begin{document}
    Lorem\footcite{homer}
    ipsum\footcite{homer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the line `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}`.

Comment: For first citations I think it would be conceptually nicer to redefine `cite:full` instead, see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`verbose`'s `cite:full` macros usually call `\usedriver` as

```
\usedriver
  {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
  {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
```

which means that they change the format for `sortname` (the name format of the 'primary' name associated with an entry, the name before the title, usually author, editor or translator in that order) to `default`.
The idea behind that is that `default` (which in the end is `given-family`) is the 'natural' name order and that `family-given/given-family` or `family-given` is only used in the bibliography to make it easier to spot the right part of the name for sorting. In the footnotes there is little issue with sorting and so `given-family` is used.

The implementation of `cite:short:interview` follows that practice to call `\usedriver` with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}`.

In the following code `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}` is removed for `cite:short:interview` (for subsequent citations) and also `cite:full` (for the first citation)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@interview{homer,
  interviewee = {Homer Simpson},
  interviewer = {Bart Simpson},
  date        = {2018-07-25},
  address     = {Springfield},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents}{interview.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{interview}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[interview]{
  addendum,
  doi,
  eprint,
  eprintclass,
  eprinttype,
  interviewer,
  interviewee,
  location,
  note,
  pubstate,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[datamodel=interview,backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{interview}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  interview   = {Interview},
}

\DeclareNameAlias{interviewee}{author}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{interview}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{interviewee}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \bibstring{interview}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{interviewer}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:short:interview}{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
    \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
      \usedriver
        {}
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \ifbibmacroundef{cite:short:\strfield{entrytype}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
    {\usebibmacro*{cite:short:\strfield{entrytype}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\begin{document}
    Lorem\footcite{homer}
    ipsum\footcite{homer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Fn.1: "Simpson, Homer. Interview Bart Simpson, 25. Juli 2018, Springfield."//Fn. 2 "Simpson, Homer. Interview Bart Simpson, 25. Juli 2018, Springfield."]