# @misc bibtex entry is not citing correctly

Tags: bibtex

I'm using an @misc bibtex entry to cite a government website in my thesis. The Bibliography compiles fine, but within the text the citation is included twice. for example text text (cite, cite).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
```

bibtex entry:

```
@misc{kinaSUR,
    author = {{Ministry for Primary Industries}},
    title = {{Kina sea urchin regions in NZ}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://fs.fish.govt.nz/Page.aspx?pk=7\&sc=SUR}},
    note = {Online; accessed 29 January 2014}
```

The double brackets for author ensure it typesets correctly, otherwise it tries to make it a first and last name and comes out a jumbled mess. It might be the problem but its the only way I could get the author to typeset correctly.

Suggestions appreciated.
Thanks

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{otago} 
\bibliography{thesis}
\citep{kinaSUR}
\end{document}
```

bibtex entry is above

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your BibTeX-entry isn't completed. There is a missing bracket and in your MWE you need a `\cite` command.

Comment: Sorry, where is the bracket missing?

Comment: You entry should be `@misc{<key>,definition}`

Comment: none of my cite keys have a second bracket, only a comma and this is the only one I have a problem with.

Answer (score 14):

For testing I downloaded the file `otago.bst` from this website: http://otago.libguides.com/content.php?pid=172484&sid=1451535

The issue is based on your entry type. The style `otago` and the resulting output require a field `year`. So if you modify your entry it works.

Correct BibTeX-Entry:

```
@misc{kinaSUR,
    author = "{Ministry for Primary Industries}",
    title = {{Kina sea urchin regions in NZ}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://fs.fish.govt.nz/Page.aspx?pk=7&sc=SUR}},
    note = {Online; accessed 29 January 2014} ,
    year=2013,
}
```

---

Here a complete MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{kinaSUR,
    author = "{Ministry for Primary Industries}",
    title = {{Kina sea urchin regions in NZ}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://fs.fish.govt.nz/Page.aspx?pk=7&sc=SUR}},
    note = {Online; accessed 29 January 2014} ,
    year=2013,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{kinaSUR}

\bibliographystyle{otago} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: You were right, I didn't have a year field as I wanted a date accessed instead, however adding a year fixed the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `filecontents` environment **without** `filecontents` package, because since the 2019 update this package is not needed anymore. Here's the updated MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@misc{kinaSUR,
    author = "{Ministry for Primary Industries}",
    title = {{Kina sea urchin regions in NZ}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://fs.fish.govt.nz/Page.aspx?pk=7&sc=SUR}},
    note = {Online; accessed 29 January 2014} ,
    year=2013,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{My article}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

Here's the reference: \cite{kinaSUR}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```