# problems with bibtex on webpage -- JSS style files

Tags: bibtex, journal-publishing

**[Original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321936/problems-citing-a-website-bibtex) has been deleted. This provides a more specific question to my problem by including the journal's style files.**

I've been told the correct citation for my purposes is

> Our suggested citation, as specified on the about Kidsdata.org page, is: [Original data source.] As cited on www.kidsdata.org, a program of the Lucile Packard Foundation for Children's Health. Retrieved on [date].

I'm trying to follow either of these examples to no success. [(1)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161762/misc-bibtex-entry-is-not-citing-correctly), [(2)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management)

I've tried both `@misc` and `@techreport`. Neither seems to work.

**Edited** to include suggestions from @UlrikeFischer below. Still getting failures.

```
@misc{la_births,
   title= {Birth Statistics Master Files},
   author= {{California Department of Public Health}},
    year= {2013},
  url={\url{http://www.kidsdata.org/topic/610/fertility-rate/}},
  note= {As cited on \url{www.kidsdata.org}, a program of the Lucile Packard Foundation for Children's Health. Accessed: July 27th, 2016}
}


@techreport{la_deaths,
    author= {{Office of Health Assessment \& Epidemiology}},
    title= {Mortality in Los Angeles County 2012: Leading causes of death and premature death with trends for 2003-2012},
    institution= {Los Angeles County Department of Public Health},
    year= {2015}
}

@techreport{un_population,
    author= {Department of Economic and Social Affairs: Population Division},
    title= {World Population Prospects: The 2012 Revision, Highlights and Advance Tables},
    institution= {United Nations},
    year= {2013},
    number= {ESA/P/WP.228}
}
```

> Running pdflatex.exe on my_file.tex...failed

I do not see the original authors on the [source site](https://www.cdph.ca.gov/data/statistics/Pages/CountyBirthStatisticalDataTables.aspx), hence the "cited on ..." (mis?)usage for the author field.

#### reproducible example below:

A reproducible example is provided below, using the above citation as the `bibliography.bib` file. This **does** compile!

```
\documentclass{jss}


\begin{document}

\cite{la_births}
\cite{la_deaths}
\cite{un_populaton}

%------------------------------------------------------------
% Bibliography
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

#### journal specific example:

A more complete example uses the journal's style files, [found here](https://www.jstatsoft.org/about/submissions) and would not require `\bibliographystyle{plain}` which is controlled by their style files.

Further, this preamble is used. Otherwise, the above example is the same. I am using Rstudio/Sweave to compile my document.

```
\documentclass[article]{jss}

% \usepackage{graphicx, color, hyperref, ae, fancyverb, natbib} % -- default JSS packages
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm} % American Math. Society Packages
\usepackage{thumbpdf} % JSS encouraged
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[font= footnotesize, labelfont= bf]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}

%% need no \usepackage{Sweave.sty}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
```

#### log output (true document)

The document fails pdflatex with 1 warning.

All ctrl+F references to "warning" reprinted below.

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperindex' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 444.

Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 444.
Package hyperref Info: Option `linktocpage' set `true' on input line 444.
Package hyperref Info: Option `plainpages' set `false' on input line 444.
)

Package thumbpdf Warning: Thumbnail data file `jss_synthACS.tpt' not found.

Package natbib Warning: Citation `la_births' on page 1 undefined on input line 
21.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `un_populaton' on page 1 undefined on input li
ne 25.
```

Comment: Where is the MWE?

Comment: You edited the question, but there is still no MWE?

Comment: You are presenting a compilable document stating is doesn't show the error and a document which is not compilable, stating it shows the error. On the other hand, go with Ulrikes suggestion and don t misuse the author field. A kind email to the editors of the cited stuff would have given you a proper author a while back.

Comment: @Johannes_B sorry... I don't understand your first part. I'm sure this is due to my own ignorance; but any clarification would be appreciated. I had been corresponding with the editors and they hadn't provided a clear answer for the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three fairly simple problems:

- There is a mismatch between the citation keys `un_population` (in the .bib) and `un_populaton` (in the .tex). The latter is missing an i.
- The author field of the `un_population` bib entry is not protected. Hence the `and` is interpreted as separating two authors with surnames `of Economic` and `Division`.
- The `url` field of the `la_births` bib entry must not have an additional `\url{}` command. The `jss` BibTeX style automatically hyperlinks the entries in the `url` fields.

Correcting these problems leads to the desired output on my end.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't misuse fields. The author field should contain the author and not some arbitrary text. If there is no person then use either "anonymus" or in your case probably better the institution:

```
@misc{la_births,
    title= {Birth Statistics Master Files},
    author= {{California Department of Public Health}},
    year= {2013},
    url={http://www.kidsdata.org/topic/610/fertility-rate/},
    note= {As cited on www.kidsdata.org, a program of the Lucile Packard Foundation for Children's Health. Accessed: July 27th, 2016}
}


\documentclass{jss}

\begin{document}
\cite{la_births}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In the first post I noted the misuse of the author field and my inability to track down the appropriate author. I clearly missed it in this re-type... Thanks for your suggestion on how to handle this.

Comment: This solution isn't working for me, although it appears to for you. Any additional suggestions would be appreciated.