# Understanding BibTeX errors

Tags: bibtex, errors

The bibtex command in TexWorks says

```
Warning--entry type for "Stratton12" isn't style-file defined
--line 359 of file bibs.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 369 of file bibs.bib
 :   
 :   year = {2012},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 629 of file bibs.bib
 : @inproceedings{Shi16
 :                     ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
```

In fact the file contains 354 lines as I uploaded [here](https://pastebin.com/ACUCN7yD)! So how he is looking for line 629 or 359?!

I don't see anything wrong with `year = {2012},` or `@inproceedings{Shi16`. Any idea?

Also, how can I resolve warnings like `Warning--to sort, need author or key in RCSB`?

Comment: You are missing a comma (",") that should finalize the previous field after its closing "`}`" or "`"`" and start the year field

Comment: For the second, you should add a "key" or an "author" field.

Comment: you have tagged this biblatex but it appears to be a bibtex question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Each `@` entry has `author`. Isn't that enough? Is there any example for that?

Comment: @mahmood no the error message claerly tells you which entry has no author look at `@misc{RCSB,`

Comment: OK I got it. It seems that while I have written URL and date in `@misc` entries, they are missed in the PDF file. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: @mahmood check here the correct fields for misc: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161766/120578

Comment: @mahmood use a bibtex style that knows about url  (the standard ones were written before the web existed) or use a general text entry and add `\url` markup explicit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning about entry type is telling you of a typo

```
@techrepor
```

is missing a `t`

The first error is a missing comma after

```
institution = {Center for Reliable and High-Performance Computing, University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign}
```

The repeated entry error is because you have two entries with the same key

```
 @inproceedings{Shi16,
```

lines 315 and 257

And the sort warning is telling that you can not sort the entries in alphabetical order if you provide no name to sort, so you need to provide the missing data or use an unsorted style.